# Subsetting from time series data

Tags: r, time-series, subset

I'm using the a built-in dataset. The data is like this.

the data starts of like this

```
data(usmacro)
```

The data is a time series. the data is from:

```
             inf       une        tbi
1953 Q1  1.7904638  2.700000  1.9800000
1953 Q2  1.5219396  2.566667  2.1533333
1953 Q3  1.0957584  2.733333  1.9566667
1953 Q4  0.9877907  3.700000  1.4733333
1954 Q1  1.3478690  5.266667  1.0600000
1954 Q2  1.2936791  5.800000  0.7900000
1954 Q3  0.9297588  5.966667  0.8833333
1954 Q4  0.7216526  5.333333  1.0200000
1955 Q1  0.6671824  4.733333  1.2233333
1955 Q2  1.0739045  4.400000  1.4833333
1955 Q3  1.7834868  4.100000  1.8566667
1955 Q4  2.3351315  4.233333  2.3366667
1956 Q1  2.9235953  4.033333  2.3266667
1956 Q2  3.3019508  4.200000  2.5666667
```

That data is a time-series. Can anyone help me how to subset a time-series? More specifically, I would like to use data from 1953, quarter 2, what code can I use?

Comment: Shane, the years column have a name or it's the rows?

Comment: it doesn't have a name, and that's why i'm having the problem. the data is called data(usmacro)

Comment: Please provide **complete** code including library statements.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is usmacro in the bvarsv package it is an mts/ts object so we can use `window` as shown below.  See `?window` for more information.  Except for the data, the code below uses no packages.

```
window(usmacro, start = c(1953, 2))
```

giving:

```
               inf       une        tbi
1953 Q2  1.5219396  2.566667  2.1533333
1953 Q3  1.0957584  2.733333  1.9566667
1953 Q4  0.9877907  3.700000  1.4733333
1954 Q1  1.3478690  5.266667  1.0600000
...snip...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
# Load data
ts <- usmacro

# See naming convention of years & quarters
timeSeries::getTime(ts)

# Filter data for '1953 Q2' or 1953.25
ts_sub <- ts[timeSeries::getTime(ts) >= 1953.25,]
```

OR here is another way that I just found on [Rob Hyndman's website](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tsibbles/) as well... I've never tried it this way but it looks pretty TIDY.

```
#libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(lubridate)

ts_sub <- ts %>% as_tsibble()
ts_sub <- filter(lubridate::yq(index) >= '1953-04-01')
```

Comment: Hi @C Jeruzal, thanks. unfortunately, the final command runs an error.

Comment: Error in df[timeSeries::getTime(ts) == 1953.25, ] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: corrected the code. try it again.  sorry about that!

Comment: thanks soo much! One final question-I was just hoping to have all the data from 1953.25 onwards, i tried the colon code in your ts_sub but it didn't see to work, any suggestions on that?@C Jeruzal

Comment: I updated the code again and added another way to try the subset using `tsibble` and `lubridate` packages... it's a bit easier to use I think and all the data is ready for tiime-series plotting.

Answer (score 0):

@Shane

You can use **dplyr** package to filter, but first, to be more easy to manipulate your dataset, let's create a column with rownames:

```
# Loading dataset
dt <- data(usmacro)

# Creating a column called 'Year' and assigning the row's names.
dt['Year'] <- rownames(dt)
```

With **tidyr** package, you can separate the Year column into two, one called **year** and other called **quarter**:

```
# Installing and loading tidyr package
install.packages(tidyr)
library('tidyr')

dt %>% separate(Year, into=c('year', 'quarter'), sep='\\s')
```

After that you just need to use dplyr to filter your data:

```
# Installing and loading **dplyr** package
install.packages(dplyr)
library('dplyr')

dt %>% filter(year==1953 & quarter=='Q2')
```

Comment: # Creating a column called 'Year' and assigning the row's names.
dt['Year'] <- rownames(dt)
Error in dt["Year"] <- rownames(dt) : replacement has length zero

This command doesn't seem to work. Maybe because it's a time series?

Comment: Shane, try to do this:

dt['Year'] <- as.character(rownames(dt))

Comment: It returns the same error. @Urantia The Player

Comment: Shane, try to upload your dataset as follow: dt <- as.data.frame(data(usmacro)) and try again.